# Wavy wall -what mud should I use to straighten it?

Tags: mudding

Do I use all purpose joint compound
https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-sheetrock-all-purpose-drywall-compound-ready-mixed-2l-pail/1000113381
or I use Durabond 90 followed by all purpose coating ?
https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-sheetrock-durabond-90-setting-type-joint-compound-15-kg-bag/1000113387
The grid in the picture represents tiles
The dotted line it represents the upper edge of the section that is curved (i.e the zone is below that line)

The H letter and the two verticals show the area where the drywall is bowed (it has a hump there, a long level put against that section rocks a little less that 1/4" at the extreme ends of the dotted line

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of using that much mud, it might be easier to remove that section of drywall and fix what is causing the hump.  Is it too much insulation or a stud out of line.

Comment: why do you want to flatten it?  drywall often has humps.

Comment: I am installing tile base board and it needs to join the tiles you see in the picture.  the existing tiles are plumb and because of that they are off the wall with like 2-3/16". @crip659 there is no insulation or furrying behind this wall was discussed in my previous posts....see the picture i just addes

Comment: _they are off the wall with like 2-3/16"_ they (the tiles?) are off the wall? How are they off the wall by 2+"? You know the drill here - some pictures showing the actual situation. I thought the wavy wall was the vertical line on the right of your sketch...

Comment: If I were you I would try to read the previous comment and the original post...

Comment: I think some of the confusion is "2-3/16". Normal (US) usage that means 2.1875". Which is **HUGE**. I think this really means "between 2/16 and 3/16" or 0.125" - 0.1875". Which is relatively speaking a lot, but much more manageable, and closer to what the picture shows. So what we really have is "how can I fill a variance of a wall surface that is up to 3/16" out of plumb."

Comment: You got it right The H section is fine

Comment: Given that it's near the bottom, it might be water damage. Which should be dealt with because there could be black mold lurking back there.

Comment: there is no water there ...the wall is dry like a desert

Comment: No reason for the downvote. So I upvoted.